# Sending value in Entry widget to Feature Class via ArcPy insertCursor?

Tags: arcpy, python, cursor

I have a python script that is adding a record to a feature class and it is working correctly. However, I now want to allow the user to enter the record details via Entry boxes. The record is being created but instead of the text from the Entry box, I'm getting numbers; .101463104.101464424

```
 def new_record():
    import arcpy
    arcpy.env.workspace = r'F:\MyProject\mygdb.gdb'
    myPath = r'F:\MyProject\mygdb.gdb'
    editRows = arcpy.da.InsertCursor('records', '*')
    print editRows.fields
    OID = 1
    ptShape = arcpy.Point(0,0)
    county = text_search_county
    rec_year = int(text_search_story_year)
    newRecord = [OID, ptShape, county, rec_year]
    editRows.insertRow(newRecord)
    del editRows


label_search_county = Label (toplevel, text="County", font="none 12 bold")
label_search_county.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)

text_search_county = Entry(toplevel, width=20)
text_search_county.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)

label_search_story_year = Label (toplevel, text="Story Year", font="none 12 bold")
label_search_story_year.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=W)

text_search_story_year = Entry(toplevel, width=20)
text_search_story_year.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=W)

insert_record = Button(toplevel, text="Insert", width=8, command=new_record)
insert_record.grid(row=7, column=1, sticky=W)
```

If tried doing county = str(text_search_county) but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `.get()` method for `Entry`s. Without it, you probably get Entrys' memory addresses instead of their values.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r'F:\MyProject\mygdb.gdb'
myPath = r'F:\MyProject\mygdb.gdb'

def new_record():
   editRows = arcpy.da.InsertCursor('records', '*')
   OID = 1
   ptShape = arcpy.Point(0,0)
   county = text_search_county.get() ### <--
   rec_year = int(text_search_story_year.get())  ### <--
   newRecord = [OID, ptShape, county, rec_year]
   editRows.insertRow(newRecord)
   del editRows
```

Note: If you don't see the changes, close Attribute Table and re-open.